# dropdownlist with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, drop-down-menu

I've got a dropdownmenu over [here](http://jsfiddle.net/KETrw/)
By hovering over the second link two fields are shown.

I do it with CSS in this fiddle.
How can I achieve the same behaviour with JS/ jQuery?

I tried

```
$(".active").hover(function(){
    $("#navi li ul").css("display","block !important");
});
```

but it won't work.
I also tried the version with cssText, but failed.
Can you help me?

Comment: Why? If the hover effect is all you need, CSS *is* the better way to solve this.

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to manipulate a site. I do not have any access to the css-files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go...

http://jsfiddle.net/KETrw/1/

Alternatively

http://jsfiddle.net/KETrw/3/

A plugin i found very usefull for these kinds of hover situations is [hoverIntent](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html), it determines the users intent when hovering over items.

Yet another alternative:

http://jsfiddle.net/KETrw/4/

---

JAVASCRIPT

```
$().ready(function(){
    $('#navi li').hover(function(){
        $(this).find('ul').toggle()
    })    
})
```

HTML

```
<div id="navi">
    <ul>
        <li style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; padding: 0px;">
            <a href="#">Link 1</a>
        </li>
        <li class="active" style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; padding: 0px;">
            <a href="#">Link 2</a>
            <ul style="display:none;">
                <li><a href="#">2a</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">2b</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; padding: 0px;"><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I like the alternative. I'll mark your question as asnwered asap. Again, ty.

Comment: Perhaps you could add some of the code from your jsfiddle links to your answer itself. Links break over time.

Answer (score 1):

`!important` does not seem to work, if you use `block` it will show the menu, but it won't hide it. Try `toggle` to hide it:

```
$(".active a").hover(function(){
    $("#navi li ul").toggle(250);
});
```